# Is it necessary and sufficient that $6$ divides $n^2$ for the positive integer $n$ to be divisible by $6$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

As the title suggests, is it a necessary and sufficient that $6$ divides $n^2$ for the positive integer $n$ to be divisible by $6$? Like, I understand the dictionary definitions of necessary and sufficient, but I don't have an idea on how to logically prove this problem...

Comment: Well, certainly if $6 \mid n$, then $6 \mid n^2$. What can you say if $6 \mid n^2$? For a start, try considering what happens if $2 \mid n^2$.

Comment: Are you aware of (unique) prime factorizations?

Comment: Note that the distinct prime factors of $n^2$ are exactly the distinct prime factors of $n$

Answer (score 5):

The main result is [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma):

> If $p$ is prime and $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.

Now $6$ divides $m$ iff $2$ and $3$ divide $m$.

Apply these two facts to $6$ divides $n^2$ to conclude that $2$ and $3$ divide $n^2$ and so that $2$ and $3$ divide $n$.

Answer (score 1):

without Euclid:  if $6|n^2$, $n^2=2^{2i}3^{2j}p_3^{2k}p_4^{2l}...p_q^{2m},\{i,j,k,l,m...\}\in N$

now take the square root of that.  for other way obvious that $6|n\Rightarrow 6|n^2$

Answer (score 1):

Another way without Euclid's lemma:  the table of squares modulo $6$ is :
$$\begin{matrix}
n\equiv {}&0 &\pm1 & \pm2&3\\[1ex]
\hline
n^2\equiv {}&0&1&-2&3
\end{matrix}$$
We see the only case with $\,n^2\equiv 0 \bmod 6$ is when $n\equiv 0$.